# Filter file in java

Tags: java, string

I want to do filter on files in Java.

Is it possible to create filter that check if the file start in 'car' and end in `color.js`

I created this code that check the end of string equals to `color.js` but how can I check if string starts with 'car'

```
File folder = new File("C:\\test);
    FilenameFilter filter = new FilenameFilter() {
        public boolean accept(File folder, String fileName) {
            return fileName.endsWith("color.js");
        }
    };

    //File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
    String[] myFiles = folder.list(filter);
```

Comment: Do you want to extend your already existing `filter` or create a new `filter` altogether and apply both of them?

Comment: `fileName.matches("car.*color\\.js")` or `fileName.startsWith("car") && fileName.endsWith("color.js")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fast and simple way:

```
public boolean accept(File folder, String fileName) {
        return fileName.endsWith("color.js") && filename.startsWith("car");
    }
```

Maybe you'll find more convinient to use [regular expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html):

```
public boolean accept(File folder, String fileName) {
        return fileName.matches("car.*color[.]js");
    }
```

But this way you should be careful with symbols that appear to be special characters in regexp patterns.

Answer (score 2):

In the same way you've used `String#endsWith`, you can use `String#startsWith`.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
public boolean accept(File folder, String fileName) {
    return fileName.endsWith("color.js") && fileName.startsWith("car");
}
```