# how get a specific file onItemClick from list view

Tags: java, android, listview

i have a folder with two files: one pdf and one xml.

When i click  on folder i want get path of xml file only.

With my code(that i post below) i get paths of both files.

Who can help me?
THANKS!

```
 private ArrayList<String> GetFiles2(File f) {
        ArrayList<String> MyFiles = new ArrayList<String>();
        //File f = new File(DirectoryPath);

        f.mkdirs();
        File[] files = f.listFiles();
        if (files.length == 0)
            return null;
        else {
            for (int i=0; i<files.length; i++)
                MyFiles.add(files[i].getPath());
        }

        System.out.println("MYFILE:"+MyFiles);
        return MyFiles;

    }
```

my result : MYFILE:

```
`[/storage/emulated/0/ordinazioni/2/23_Agosto_2017_09_44_51_AM.xml,` /storage/emulated/0/ordinazioni/2/23_Agosto_2017_09_44_51_AM.pdf]
```

Comment: try         System.out.println("MYFILE:"+MyFiles[0]);

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filter file in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14097901/filter-file-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the overriden version of `File#listFiles(FileFilter)` to get specific files from a directory.

```
    File[] files = f.listFiles(new FileFilter() {
        @Override
        public boolean accept(File pathname) {
            return pathname.getName().endsWith(".xml");
        }
    });
```

**Full implementation :**

```
private ArrayList<String> getXmlFiles(File directory) {
    ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
    directory.mkdirs();
    File[] files = directory.listFiles(new FileFilter() {
        @Override
        public boolean accept(File pathname) {
            return pathname.getName().endsWith(".xml");
        }
    });
    for(File f : files)
        names.add(f.getPath());

    System.out.println("MYFILE:" + names);
    return files.length > 0 ? names : null;
}
```

Anyway I recommend you to return an empty list insteand of `null` to avoid NPE issues (Just `return names`)

Comment: i need to insert into arraylist<String> path of xml file not true or false

Answer (score 0):

You can change your `for`-loop like this for example:

```
for (int i=0; i<files.length; i++) {
    if(files[i].getPath().endsWith(".xml")) {
        MyFiles.add(files[i].getPath());
    }
}
```

this will add to the MyFiles list only the paths of the xml files in the praticular folder

Answer (score 0):

For getting a specific file location use this code,

```
File dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File yourFile = new File(dir, "path/to/the/file/inside/the/sdcard.ext");
```

eg ;

`"/AAlist/"+serialno.get(position).trim()+".jpg"`